# Api does not refresh after each request

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm working on api project and got one problem. My api is written in DRF and the response is being displayed on Vue project. The problem is, api should refresh after each request (browser refresh).

At first i display all the filtered objects on my vue page (get request). Each object contains a button which triggers POST request (on drf behalf it creates instance of another model + modifies the current model's instance - boolean field changes its state). Once the POST has been send and page has been refreshed, the api should not return the instance anymore as the boolean has changed. I guess there is some kind of storage or something. How can I keep it refreshing?

DRF views:

```
*class UserAccountCreation(mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = ActivityForm.objects.filter(Confirmed=False)
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    data = {}

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ActivityFormSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            password = "1234"
            user = f"User{User.objects.count()+1}"
            self.data["user"] = f"User{User.objects.count()+1}"
            self.data["email"] = serializer.validated_data["email"]
            self.data["response"] = "User created"
            serializer.save(username=user, password=password)
            return Response(self.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)*
```

DRF signals - boolean changes here:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_UserAccount(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_form = ActivityForm.objects.filter(Email=instance.email).first()
        if user_form:
            user_form.Confirmed = True #// bolean changes here
            user_form.save()
            newAccount, created = UserAccount.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, form=user_form)
            newAccount.save()
        else:
            print("Manually added user")
```

VUE functions - response is being kept in variable which is the base for my loop:

```
async getAllrequests(){
        this.apiResponse = ""
        await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/allforms/').then(response =>{
            this.apiResponse = response.data
            console.log(this.apiResponse)
        })
    },
    async CreateUser(user, evt){
        console.log(user)
        const params = {
            email:user.Email
        }
        await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/allforms/', params).then(response =>{
            evt.target.innerText = "Created"
            evt.target.disabled = true
        })
        
    },
```

template:

```
<b-card
            v-for="user in apiResponse"
            :key="user.Email"
            :title="user.Email"
            tag="article"
            style="max-width: 20rem; max-height: 20rem;"
            class="mb-2 mr-2"
            >
            <b-card-text>
                Age: {{CheckResponseValue(user.Age)}}
                <br>
                Activity: {{CheckResponseValue(user.Activity)}}
            </b-card-text>

            <b-button type="submit" variant="primary" v-on:click="CreateUser(user, $event)">Create</b-button>
        </b-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay fixed :) DRF documentation helped me this time. The problem was that list() used self.queryset instead of self.get_queryset

Comment: Really wished you would have described in a bit more detail what went wrong. I am facing the same issue or similar. I am curios what exactly did you change?